# Nothing shows up in the console when scraping a website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I'm doing a personal project where I want to scrape some game rankings off a website, but I'm unable to locate in the HTML the titles of the games that I want to scrape.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://newzoo.com/insights/rankings/top-20-core-pc-games/', (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);


    //var table = $('#ranking');
    //console.log(table.text());
    $('.ranking-row').each((i,el) => {
      const title = $(el).find('td').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
      console.log(title);
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const title = $(el).find('td').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
```

to

```
const title = $(el).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
```

**PS:** To debug xpaths, use the chrome debugger. If you go to this specific site and search for `.ranking-row td td:nth-child(1)`, you will see that nothing is returned. But if you do `.ranking-row td:nth-child(2)` you would get the desired result. 
This is a simple xpath error caused by looking for the same `td` twice and using the wrong index in `nth-child`.